# Removing a fragment not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to remove a fragment and show a toast when I click a textView. My code shows the toast, but doesn't remove the fragment.

**My method:**

```
public void hide(View view) {

        My_frag myFrag= new My_frag();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.remove(myFrag);
        transaction.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

**My_frag class:**

```
public class My_frag extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_frag_layout, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At some point you must create and add the `Fragment` correct? You are re-creating the fragment in your `hide(...)` method so you are trying to remove something that has never been added. Sure you may have added *an* instance, but not *the* instance you are trying to remove.
Instead, create a global variable `Fragment fragToRemove` in your `Activity`. When you create the fragment (that is where ever you do `transaction.add(fragToRemove = new My_Frag);`) you will hold an instance. then change your `transaction.remove(myFrag)` to `transaction.remove(fragToRemove)` and it should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, I add the fragment from a button click that happens before. I want the fragment to go away when I click into my editText view. I will try your suggestions and leave a comment. Thanks

Comment: It worked. I just put `My_frag myFrag= new My_frag();
` at the top of my application and deleted that line in both my `show()` and `hide()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Take the  instance of Fragment Transaction other than that was taken while adding fragment to activity and call remove method on that and pass the same instance of Fragment which was used at the time.

**Example:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    BlankFragment blankFragment;

    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_button);
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        blankFragment=new BlankFragment(); //Fragment instance 
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_layout,blankFragment).commit();
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(blankFragment).commit(); //created different 
        }
    });

}
```

In the same way you can do in fragments also and can also remove fragment X on the click of component of fragment X.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments can be "attached" and "added", you need use reverse operations, according to FragmentPagerAdapter::instantiateItem

```
manager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit()
```

or

```
manager.beginTransaction().detach(it).commit()
```

Something like this:

```
fragmentList.forEach {
        manager.beginTransaction().remove(it).commit()
        manager.beginTransaction().detach(it).commit()
    }
```